# How to get value of embedded key in JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to get the value of an embedded key in JSON, but I keep getting the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

The JSON is:

```
{"id": "example", "metadata": {"operation": "retrieve", "provider": "Oxford University Press", "schema": "RetrieveEntry"}, "results": [{"id": "example", "language": "en-gb", "lexicalEntries": [{"entries": [{"etymologies": ["late Middle English: from Old French, from Latin exemplum, from eximere \u2018take out\u2019, from ex- \u2018out\u2019 + emere \u2018take\u2019. Compare with sample"], "pronunciations": [{"audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/example_gb_1.mp3", "dialects": ["British English"], "phoneticNotation": "IPA", "phoneticSpelling": "\u026a\u0261\u02c8z\u0251\u02d0mp(\u0259)l"}, {"dialects": ["British English"], "phoneticNotation": "IPA", "phoneticSpelling": "\u025b\u0261\u02c8z\u0251\u02d0mp(\u0259)l"}], "senses": [{"definitions": ["a thing characteristic of its kind or illustrating a general rule"], "examples": [{"text": "advertising provides a good example of an industry where dreams have faded"}], "id": "m_en_gbus0339130.007", "semanticClasses": [{"id": "example", "text": "Example"}], "shortDefinitions": ["thing characteristic of its kind"], "subsenses": [{"definitions": ["a written problem or exercise designed to illustrate a rule"], "examples": [{"text": "a workbook and a data set will enable the researcher to follow worked examples"}], "id": "m_en_gbus0339130.012", "semanticClasses": [{"id": "mathematical_expression", "text": "Mathematical_Expression"}], "shortDefinitions": ["problem or exercise illustrating rule"]}], "synonyms": [{"language": "en", "text": "specimen"}, {"language": "en", "text": "sample"}, {"language": "en", "text": "exemplar"}, {"language": "en", "text": "exemplification"}, {"language": "en", "text": "instance"}, {"language": "en", "text": "case"}, {"language": "en", "text": "representative case"}, {"language": "en", "text": "typical case"}, {"language": "en", "text": "case in point"}, {"language": "en", "text": "illustration"}], "thesaurusLinks": [{"entry_id": "example", "sense_id": "t_en_gb0005163.001"}]}, {"definitions": ["a person or thing regarded in terms of their fitness to be imitated"], "examples": [{"text": "it is important that parents should set an example"}, {"text": "he followed his brother's example and deserted his family"}], "id": "m_en_gbus0339130.014", "semanticClasses": [{"id": "example", "text": "Example"}], "shortDefinitions": ["person or thing imitated"], "synonyms": [{"language": "en", "text": "precedent"}, {"language": "en", "text": "lead"}, {"language": "en", "text": "guide"}, {"language": "en", "text": "model"}, {"language": "en", "text": "pattern"}, {"language": "en", "text": "blueprint"}, {"language": "en", "text": "template"}, {"language": "en", "text": "paradigm"}, {"language": "en", "text": "exemplar"}, {"language": "en", "text": "ideal"}, {"language": "en", "text": "standard"}], "thesaurusLinks": [{"entry_id": "example", "sense_id": "t_en_gb0005163.002"}]}]}], "language": "en-gb", "lexicalCategory": {"id": "noun", "text": "Noun"}, "phrases": [{"id": "for_example", "text": "for example"}, {"id": "make_an_example_of", "text": "make an example of"}], "text": "example"}, {"entries": [{"notes": [{"text": "\"be exampled\"", "type": "wordFormNote"}], "pronunciations": [{"audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/example_gb_1.mp3", "dialects": ["British English"], "phoneticNotation": "IPA", "phoneticSpelling": "\u026a\u0261\u02c8z\u0251\u02d0mp(\u0259)l"}, {"dialects": ["British English"], "phoneticNotation": "IPA", "phoneticSpelling": "\u025b\u0261\u02c8z\u0251\u02d0mp(\u0259)l"}], "senses": [{"definitions": ["be illustrated or exemplified"], "examples": [{"text": "the extent of Allied naval support is exampled by the navigational specialists provided"}], "id": "m_en_gbus0339130.016", "shortDefinitions": ["be illustrated or exemplified"]}]}], "language": "en-gb", "lexicalCategory": {"id": "verb", "text": "Verb"}, "phrases": [{"id": "for_example", "text": "for example"}, {"id": "make_an_example_of", "text": "make an example of"}], "text": "example"}], "type": "headword", "word": "example"}], "word": "example"}
```

The value I want is found at `"results" > "lexicalEntries" > "entries" > "senses" > "definitions"`.

How can I get the value from this key using Python?

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.request

app_id = "XXXXXX"
app_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
language = "en-gb"
word_id = "example"
url1 = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id.lower()

r1 = urllib.request.Request(url1, headers={"app_id": app_id, "app_key": app_key})

with urllib.request.urlopen(r1) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    data = json.dumps(data)
    #print(data)
    #print(data['results']['lexicalEntries']['entries']['senses']['definitions'])
    print(data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions'])
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this in python? Can you post some code?
You can also use json path queries to achieve what you want, there are some libs in python for that

Comment: @FabioBohnenberger https://pastebin.com/UzkYF1MB

Comment: why do you use `json.dumps` right after `json.loads`?

Comment: it gets loaded in as a dict, so that converts it to JSON

Comment: Calling `dumps()` converts the data to a string, so you don't have a dictionary anymore.  Take that out.

Comment: That works @JohnGordon, but how can I remove the `['`and `']`. I don't want to just use .replace(), because the value might contain an apostrophe

Comment: Removing `dumps()` like @JohnGordon said, the answer bellow should work

Comment: It's printing with `['` and `']` because it's a _string inside of a list_.  If you only want the first value in the list, add another `[0]` on the end of the print statement: `print(...['definitions'][0])`

Comment: @JohnGordon if I there multiple values, how can I print them all without the `['']`?

Comment: To just print them, use a loop `for definition in ...['definitions']: print(definition)`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just us requests do to the get and json parsing altogether.  See if this works for you.

```
import requests
 
app_id = "XXXXXX"
app_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
language = "en-gb"
word_id = "example"
url1 = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id.lower()
 
data = requests.get(url1, headers={"app_id": app_id, "app_key": app_key}).json()
 
print(data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions'])
```

Comment: I still get this error: `File "project.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['definitions'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Sounds like you might not have a json object, perhaps it's a string?

Comment: @ChopsKingsland This exact code worked for me, so you must not be loading the json correctly.  Can you update the question to show the exact code you're using to load the json?

Comment: @Updated the answer.